# How to fetch and display data from Invision Power board Rest API

Tags: php, json, rest, api, invision-power-board

what would be the best way to get data into html/php to display them in browser. All data is from Invision Power board Rest API. - https://invisioncommunity.com/developers/rest-api

How can I display them?
Example: I need only all usernames and 5 latest topics from specific category.

In endpoint I only get out one of them.

```
<?php
$communityUrl = 'https://www.example.com/ips4/';
$apiKey = 'c7a349a1629f02cd2855a58d77646f6d';
$endpoint = '/core/hello';
$endpoint = '/core/members';

$curl = curl_init( $communityUrl . 'api' . $endpoint );
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH    => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD     => "{$apiKey}:"
) );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
```

Comment: What do you have inside that $response variable? print_r() it to see what did you collect.

Comment: With $response I get all data from one $endpoint

But my question would be - How to get specific data from that endpoint.

Comment: Well, hmm...response depends on the endpoint you called and the parameters you passed. So you have to do some research on this API...

Answer (score 0):

That's the way to achieve that. Keep in mind that '2' is the forum ID that you want to get the posts displayed. You can read more at the [documentation](https://invisioncommunity.com/developers/rest-api?endpoint=forums/posts/GETindex) of the API but the example i gave you will work like a charm.

```
$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
$curl = curl_init('https://www.YOURSITE.com/community/api/index.php?/forums/topics&forums=2&sortDir=desc');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{$apiKey}:"
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$obj = json_decode($response);

if (isset($obj->results)) {
    return $obj->results;
} else {
    return 'error';
}
```